# jQuery mobile Ajax spinning wheel

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I try to show some spinning wheel while ajax is loading some data for the next page to be shown, I can catch the ajax start and ajax stop events correctly as I can see them from console.log but I cant see the spinning wheels!

```
  $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
            console.log("started");
            $('#loading').show();        
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", msg, false);
    }).ajaxStop(function(){
                console.log("stopped");
                $('#loading').hide();
                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            });
```

Funny thing is wheels works when I go back to previous page, but not when I go to another page with

```
     $.mobile.changePage("settings.html", {
                transition: "flip",
                reverse: false
            });
```

Comment: if the ajax is short enough, JQM will prevent the loader from showing up - or it did for me at least... maybe try extending the time of the backend script to see if that helps? also, try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7817832/467164

Comment: @Zathrus Writer THANKS! can you write your answer so I will accept it, that link helped

Comment: if that link helped, then please upvote the answer from that link and delete this question, as it is a duplicate of the previous one ;-)

Comment: this did the trick very well

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420023/jquery-mobile-problems-getting-showpageloadingmsg-to-work-with-pagebeforeshow/7817832#7817832

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem;

$('body').addClass('ui-loading');

$('body').removeClass('ui-loading');

For more detail see;

[jQuery Mobile - Problems getting showPageLoadingMsg to work with pagebeforeshow or pagebeforeceate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420023/jquery-mobile-problems-getting-showpageloadingmsg-to-work-with-pagebeforeshow/7817832#7817832)